# Replace Contents of NSTextFieldCell *During* Editing?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I'm trying to boldface the contents of an NSTextFieldCell if certain text is entered by the user **while the NSTextFieldCell is being edited.**

So far I've got this:

In awakeFromNib:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldCellDidChange:)  name:NSControlTextDidChangeNotification object:theNSTableView];
```

The method:

```
- (void) textFieldCellDidChange: (id) sender
{
    //successfully captures contents of the NSTextFieldCell prior to the 
    //start of editing
    NSString * textOfMyNSTextFieldCell = [myNSTextFieldCell stringValue];

    //attempts to capture the current edited contents of the NSTextFieldCell while
    //editing is still in progress:
    //but DOES NOT YET WORK:
    NSText *fieldEditor = [myTableView currentEditor];
    textOfMyNSTextFieldCell = [fieldEditor string];
}
```

Is it possible to capture the edited contents of an NSTextFieldCell while editing is still in progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the NSTextFieldCell's stringValue after a change is made, subclass NSTextFieldCell and implement this:

```
- (void) textDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"NSTextFieldCell noticed that text did change to: %@", self.stringValue) ;
    NSLog(@"Was notified by: \n%@", notification.object) ;
    NSLog(@"which is its controlView's currentEditor: \n%@", ((NSTextField*)self.controlView).currentEditor) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this info, John. Will this method be called on every keypress during editing, or, is it only called after editing is complete?

Comment: In my testing, it was called after every keystroke.